# How do you remove an item from from itembuilder using Dissmissable and the item is from Firestore?

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dismiss

```
  @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
        return Scaffold(
          body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: Firestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .document(widget.uid)
                .collection('lists')
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return !snapshot.hasData
                  ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                  : ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                        final list = snapshot.data.documents;
                        return Dismissible(
                          // Dismissed function
                          key: UniqueKey(),
                          onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
                            setState(() {
    
                              // This is where I would like to remove the element
                              // snapshot.data.remove(index);
                              
                            });
                          },
                          secondaryBackground: Container(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text('Delete',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.start),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                          background: Container(),
                          child: Card(
                            child: Center(
                              child: new Container(
                                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                                child: new Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    new Text(data['listName']),
                                    new Text(data['Description'])
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                        );
                      },
                    );
            },
          ),
```

- The whole goal is to make a card element disappear and delete that item too from the Firestore.
- I thought about placing each item into a map then building the cards from the map. I would rather not do it that way.

Any help is appreciated and hopefully, we can solve this together :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the document reference first by doing this:

Iterate over this: `snapshot.data.documents` then `snapshot.data.documents[i].documentID`

then this:

```
onDismissed: (direction) async {
    await Firestore.instance.runTransaction(
      (transaction) async {
        await transaction.delete(your doc ref here);
      },
    );
  },
```

Comment: Would a reference to the documentation look like this? snapshot.data.documents